# paging in entity framework using asp.net mvc application (using aspx)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to implement paging functionality in ASP.NET MVC application (aspx) using the instructions given in the below article

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

I am struck trying to find out how to implement below instructions using aspx,

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<ContosoUniversity.Models.Student>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
```

Page

```
@(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount

@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", 
    new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
```

I am using Entity Framework for the above application.

Comment: why are you using aspx?  or I guess if you have to , why don't you look for an aspx tutorial on how to implement paging .  This can definetly be done , but there is going to be so much modifications .   are you even using MVC ?   you realize that you can write this in c# razor and have aspx and .cshtml side yb side in a project , right?

Comment: Yes i have to, its a requirement, tried looking up for answers without luck on paging implementation in ASP.NET MVC using aspx. Yes i know that we can have both aspx and .cshtml side by side but the requirement is such we need to use aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use ASP.NET Server tags <%:--  %>

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master"    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<PagedList.IPagedList<ContosoUniversity.Models.Student>>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="PagedList.Mvc" %>


<%:(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of Model.PageCount%>

<%: Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", 
new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))%>
```

EDIT :

Details on using inline server tags : 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976112

Comment: Thanks Jags for helping me out, but the problem is i already have a model which inherits a different model which is IEnumerable, how do i address this issue ? sorry i am new to this Jags

Comment: Not exactly clear what you are expecting but to bind your model to you view you just need to put that in the @Page tag as shown above in inherits attribute Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<YOUR MODEL CLASS>".